# How to get user desktop notifications from a sudo-run systemd service on Wayland?

Tags: systemd, wayland, plasma, notifications, notify-send

I'm running KDE Plasma on Nobara (Wayland), a Fedora-based distro. I'm brand new to Wayland and Nobara/Fedora, and have very limited experience with systemd.

I have a bash script that sends a desktop notification with success, warning or error, depending on the outcome of the action.

- When i run the script manually (not sudo), i get a desktop notification.
- When i run the notification command in Terminal (not sudo), i get a desktop
  notification.
- When i set up the /etc/systemd/system service, i do not get desktop
  notification, and i get an error in journalctl (the script otherwise runs fine):

> Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Example notification within the script:

```
notify-send -a 'Successful!' -u low -i vcs-normal
```

systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Script
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Nice=10
IOSchedulingClass=2
IOSchedulingPriority=7
ExecStart=/home/username/.local/bin/test.sh
User=username
Group=users
```

My search indicates that the root-run systemd service doesn't have access to the user's desktop to put a notification. I [saw an attempt around it](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/desktop-notifications-from-systemd-service/17672/6), which was to add this to the service file:

```
[Service]
User=username
Environment=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/%U/bus
```

In my case, it stopped the error in the journal, but it did not give me the desktop notification.

I'm aware i can run systemd services as the user with `systemd --user start test` service files placed in `~/.config/systemd/user`, and the notifications will work (i have managed to achieve that). But in this instance i would like to run this script as root.

Thanks :)

Comment: `User=username` will prevent your service from having root-access.  In that case, it's similar to using `systemd --user`, just without the inherited environment.  Try setting `XAUTHORITY`, `DISPLAY`, `WAYLAND_DISPLAY`.  These seem to be used in my wayland session too. Run `env` to see what environment variables are set, and try to mimic that. . It's a bit tough to figure out what to set, especially when some are dynamically generated.  That's why the `--user` bus makes things so much easier and why it's my recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran `env` to get some variables and i tried various permutations. I might have the right info, but the wrong syntax or something. Here's my added line: `Environment="DISPLAY=:0" "WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0" "XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/xauth_oYYdtx"`. Unfortunately no notification appeared. No error in journalctl.